# CSS3 Animation and Transition Together

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Here is a test I created to show my situation

http://jsfiddle.net/2vN2S/

```
/* Setting up the "myAnim1" for all browser types
-------------------------------------------------*/
 @keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Firefox */
 @-moz-keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Safari and Chrome */
 @-webkit-keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Opera */
 @-o-keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
/* Attaching the animations to the elements
Notice the difference between timing!!
-------------------------------------------------*/

body {
    display:inline-block;

    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease;
    transition: 0.3s ease;

    animation:myAnim1  5s steps(2, end);
    -moz-animation:myAnim1 5s steps(2, end) infinite;
    -webkit-animation:myAnim1 5s steps(2, end) infinite;
}
```

As you can see, I've set up a stepped animation, and a transition for the body background. What I expected was the transition to create the 0.3 second "smoothness" (easing) between each step of the animation, however, it looks like the animation takes the whole control of the background color.

Is there any way to create something like that in an easy way?

Comment: are you wanting a defined amount of time for each background color to show? Or just a smooth transition between the background colors?

Comment: In my eample, defined amount of time to show. I want smooth transitions between those steps. Actually what I "exactly" want is to find a way to use the transitions and animations together (if there is a logical way to do this).

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of steps works `steps(36,end)`

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DeepakKamat/y2vWp/4/

Comment: Hey, thank you for the edit. However you've completely removed the steps.. And this means, the "smooth transition effect" is not caused by the transitions, but the animation itself. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Ohh, yeah. But if you want the steps to do the transition then why are you using CSS transition ?

Comment: Try increasing the steps, maybe  `steps(26, end)`

Comment: Oh, the initial question was not asked to create a smooth animation. it is asked to discover a way to use transition and animations at the same time (possibility of it). My main purpose is not to create an animation with smooth transitions between steps, but to find a way to use transition between various animation keyframes. This may be a way of using transition with 0.3 timing for every change of step that happens with 5 seconds of delays (will still have the long "step" effect with really smooth transitions inbetween).

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that because the purpose of keyframes is to create your own personalized easing effect. You can't combine it with transition, there is no sense in that.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>CSS Transitions trigger if the state of the element changes, e.g. it's `:hover`ed or it gets a new class from JS. Steps of CSS animation aren't changes of state, so they don't trigger transitions.</strike> Maybe this explanation was wrong and the problem is that one property can't be animated by different mechanisms in the same time.

If you need smooth transitions between steps, you can use an ordinary linear animation instead of step animation, like this:

```
@keyframes myAnim1 {
    0% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    45% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    95% {
        background-color: #31f4dc;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: #212121;
    }
}
```

([edited JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/2vN2S/15/))